# C++ & CLion - Having problems with a platform-specific code

Tags: c++, clion

I am having problems with CLion and my multi-platform code. Let's say that the main function looks like this:

```cpp
#ifdef _WIN32
cout << "win" << endl;
#endif

#ifdef linux
...
#endif
```

The problem is that CLion editor marks stripped code (that between #ifs) (for lin & win) as a comment and I it's harder for me to code (I have no hints because CLion treats it as a comment + I am learning WinAPI, so I need those). In Unity I had the following solution:

```cs
#if UNITY_SERVER || UNITY_EDITOR
//code
#endif
```

Then code was stripped from client build + I was able to code in the IDE.

Does anyone know what can I do?

**Edit 1:**
There is no problem with the building. If you have InteliJ based IDE, then put a fragment of your code in a comment - that's how it looks for me between #ifs.

Comment: First of all please create a [mcve] and [edit] your question to show it. Then also include a complete and full copy-paste (as text) of the build errors you get (if you get build errors). Also please take some time to read or refresh [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: "CLion editor marks stripped code..." i dont understand what you mean with "stripped", but so far so good ".. and I am unable to build a code" now I am lost. Why are you unable to build the code? Do you get compiler errors? Please include a [mcve] and the error

Comment: There is no problem with building. The problem is that when code is between #ifs, IDE makes it it look like a comment

Comment: you mean code highlighting? Thats just colors, no? How does this prevent you from writing code?

Comment: Saying "I am unable to do X" does not explain what your problem is. It just imples that there is something that prevents you to do X, but what that something is stays unknown

Comment: I don't have hints and it makes stuff highly harder. I am learning WinAPI and I need those.

Comment: please clarify your question. That last comment makes everything a lot clearer

Comment: How about defining those variables when you want to work on the code sections inside the blocks?

Comment: Well, I am quite fresh to CLion (usually worked with PhpStorm & InteliJ). I don't know how can I do it.

Comment: It seem you need more *abstration*. Try to abstract out the platform-specific features into base-classes that can be inherited from, and where the child-classes handles the platform-specific implementation in a way that is opaque from the use of those classes. Then every platform should have the same interface and IDE "hints" will be usable for all platforms. It will also mean less conditional compilation.

Comment: Seems like a good idea. I regret that I didn't think about this.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-8415) is your problem. The issue has no universal solution. In `foreign` compilation branch some symbols can absent (the `mmap` calls is a good example).
You can get a hint for IDE to process the `foreign` non-compiled code by [macro-hint](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/detecting-origin-of-cmake-invocation.html) `__CLION_IDE__`

Just modify your code to

```
#ifdef _WIN32 || __CLION_IDE__
cout << "win" << endl;
#endif

#ifdef linux || __CLION_IDE__
cout << "linux" << endl;
#endif
```

Comment: Well, there is a problem with this too. It says `Extra tokens at end of #ifdef directive` and the only IDE suggestion is to comment a second condition...